# Кодировка при получении ответа с HTTP сервера в MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

MS SQL 2014
Получаю данные с сервера при помощи sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1'

В ответе все русские буквы выглядят как знаки вопроса ???

С сервера возвращаются UTF-8

Понятно что дело в кодировке, но когда я делаю полю ответа COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin или любую другую, ничего не меняется.

Comment: Какой тип переменной в которой храните ответ с сервера? Надеюсь `nvarchar`?

Comment: Есть способ использовать `EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @objectID, 'ResponseBody'` это ответ в `varbinary`. Потом преобразовать его в `varchar` или `nvarchar`.